# How to get a webgrid selected row values of using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a webgrid in which i have 3 columns what i want is to catch the all the columns of a row and display it on a alert message for example a row has 3 columns teamname,description and usercount, when user click on the any of this column user must have the 3 details values on the alert message. how can i do that have no idea.please help.
here is my view with webgrid.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.TeamList.ToList(), canPage: true, rowsPerPage:10);
        }
        @grid.WebGridSelectAll(
            headerStyle: "gridHeader",
            tableStyle: "table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin",
            checkBoxValue: "TeamId",
            columns: new[]{
                grid.Column("TeamName",format: @<a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.TeamId" data-dialogmodalbind=".dialog_content3">@item.TeamName</a>,header: Html.CustomText("lblCTTeamName", "Team Name")),
                grid.Column("Description",format: @<a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.TeamId" data-dialogmodalbind=".dialog_content3">@item.Description</a>, header: Html.CustomText("lblDescription", "Description"), canSort: false),
                grid.Column("UserCount",format: @<a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.TeamId" data-dialogmodalbind=".dialog_content3">@item.UserCount</a>, header: Html.CustomText("lblCTUserCount", "# of User(s)"))   
            }
        )
</div>
```

Comment: If your redirecting to separate view, what is the point of using jquery as opposed to a normal link? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just i want to catch all the td values of a row .

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the method to `public ActionResult Details(string teamname, string description, int usercount)`?

Comment: no sir i want to give an alert message on the same page which contains all the columns of the selected row like teamname,description and the usercount. did u get me?

Comment: OK, You should edit your answer to make that clear. I'll post an answer shortly (but not sure what the point of this is - cant they just see those values in the table anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the values of the 3 columns in a row, you can use the following (note I'm not familiar with the html generated by WebGrid so the selectors may need to be adjusted)

```
$('.details').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the table row
  var links = row.find('a'); // get the 3 hyperlinks
  var teamName = links.eq(0).text();
  var description = links.eq(1).text();
  var userCount = links.eq(1).text();
  alert(teamName + ' ' + description + ' ' userCount); // adjust format as required
});
```

Comment: What if the value is `bool`? Can you still do `.text()`?

Comment: @DylanChensky, Not clear what your asking. What are you rendering for the `bool` (text, or a checkbox)?

Comment: Is an `@Html.Dropdownlist` with yes and no options

Comment: @DylanChensky, If its a form control, then you need to use `.val()` - e.g. `$(yourDropDown).val();` but if your having problems, then ask a new question with the relevant code :)